# Get object from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I currently have an array `productList` and i'm attempting to iterate through each object of it, currently productList holds the following:

```
[ '-M6QFLnrgFx0vDp0SNOK': { qty: 4, price: 0, productId: '-M6QFLnrgFx0vDp0SNOK' }, 
  '-M6QK1DAWknNd8mxIDYB': { qty: 1, price: 0, productId: '-M6QK1DAWknNd8mxIDYB' } ]
```

[image]
I need to access productId within each object of the array to place it into a Firebase Promises array.  My code currently looks like:

```
  productsList.forEach(product =>{
                var tempProduct = product;
                console.log(tempProduct.productId);
                console.log(product.productId);

            promises.push(admin.database().ref(`Core/${product.productId}/price`).once('value'))      

            });
```

Items are added to the productList array with the following code which allows me to collate all of the item's qty within a seperate array that has the same productId value:

```
            var item = itemSnap.val();
            var itemArray = item.split(",")

            if (productsList[itemArray[0]]!==undefined){ 
                 //PRODUCT LIST ALREADY EXISTS GET QTY AND ADD QTY
                var currentItem =productsList[itemArray[0]]
                var currentQty =currentItem.qty;
                var addedQty = Number(itemArray[2]);
                var totalQty = currentQty+addedQty;
                currentItem.qty =totalQty
                //REPLACE OBJECT IN PRODUCTLIST
                productsList[itemArray[0]] = currentItem;


            }else{
                //THIS IS THE PRODUCT OBJECT OF PRODUCTLIST
                var merchId ={
                    qty:Number(itemArray[2]),
                    price:0.00,
                    productId: itemArray[0]
                }
                //DOES NOT EXIST SO ADD TO IT
                productsList[itemArray[0]] = merchId;

            }
```

I fear that there must be a simple solution to this, can anyone help?

Comment: Your productlist array is invalid right now. I assume you're missing braces before and after each entry? Moreover, what does `item` / `itemArray` look like?

Comment: Your data structure is invalid. There's no _associative array_ in JS. You cannot have an array like `[key: {..}, key2: {...}] `. After restructuring the array, you can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the properties as an array.

Comment: What's there is literally what it shows within the Console.log so do i need to change the way i iterate through the original item list?

Comment: Something has gone wrong then in you copying it here because what is shown is indeed invalid structure. You are either missing starting `{` for each object or you don't have array at all as denoted by the outer `[]` and they should be `{}`

Comment: Okay, it has to be either

`[{ '-M6QFLnrgFx0vDp0SNOK': { qty: 4, price: 0, productId: '-M6QFLnrgFx0vDp0SNOK' }}, 
  {'-M6QK1DAWknNd8mxIDYB': { qty: 1, price: 0, productId: '-M6QK1DAWknNd8mxIDYB' }} ] `

or

`{ '-M6QFLnrgFx0vDp0SNOK': { qty: 4, price: 0, productId: '-M6QFLnrgFx0vDp0SNOK' }, 
  '-M6QK1DAWknNd8mxIDYB': { qty: 1, price: 0, productId: '-M6QK1DAWknNd8mxIDYB' } }`

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the console.log the original array is formed from a Firebase  Snapshot of string values... what i want to do is as i iterate through that snapshot if my productList already contains a value that matches the current iteration...add that qty to the productlist value

Comment: Stringify the data before logging it then you can copy the json directly from console

Comment: So when i stringify it, it only prints []